# Finding PMF for function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be the number of people waiting for a bus. Assuming $X$ takes on a geometric distribution that starts at $0$ rather than $1$, we have $p_{X}(k) = (1 - p)^{k}p$ for $k \geq 0$. Suppose that the bus has a capacity of $M$ passengers.

(a) Find the PMF for $Y = \text{max}\{X - M, 0\}$, which represents the number of passengers left behind.

(b) Determine $\mathbb{E}[Y]$

---

I am stuck on part $(a)$. I'm trying to work backwards:

$$P(Y = y) = P(X - M = 0) = P(X = M) = (1 - p)^{M}p.$$

I don't know if this is right, though. Also it doesn't account for the maximum function.

Then, I think that $E(Y) = 1/p$. But I also think that this is wrong, because this would be the same for $X$.

Comment: What the value of Y is there are $M$ of fewer people waiting?  What if $M+$ people are waiting?  What's the probability of that?  What if $M+2$ people are waiting?

Comment: If there are $M$ or fewer people waiting, then it's $X - M$. If $M+$ people are waiting, it's still $X - M$, I think. The probability of that happening is $(1-p)^{X-M}p^{X}$ ?

Comment: If there are $M$ or fewer people waiting it's $0$, because $X-M\leq 0$.  $Y$ is the number of people left at the bus stop.